# Making a binary package for my open source project

Tags: linux, python, pip

I currently have the following open source project, https://github.com/nadermx/backgroundremover I followed the tutorial https://betterscientificsoftware.github.io/python-for-hpc/tutorials/python-pypi-packaging/ and everything seems fine.  People can install it via `pip install backgroundremover`.

The issue arises because some one asked for me to offer it as a binary.  I went head and uploaded wheel, https://github.com/nadermx/backgroundremover/tree/main/dist but I am unsure what else I have to modify to get the option to say install backgroundremover-binary?

Comment: Enough information to understand, suggest, and test a solution to your problem needs to be **included in the question itself**; see [mre] guidelines. Links are fine as supplemental information, but a question needs to still be valid (read: helpful to others) even if they break.

Comment: In general, though, what leads you to think you _need_ to do anything else? If your program is pure Python, there's nothing that needs to be compiled to a native binary in the first place, and there's nothing in the question that says that this isn't the case.

Comment: Note that a lot of users who might ask for a "binary" are _really_ asking for a package _for their distro_ -- a RPM, or Debian package, or Arch package, or so forth (though others might be asking for something like an executable made by pyinstaller, cx_freeze, or similar tools that bundles a Python interpreter in). If neither you nor we know what the person who asked you for "a binary" meant, there's no possible way this question could be narrow and specific enough to answer.